# jQuery slider range: apply range as a filter on table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filtering

For my internship I have to make a filter for a table which has to show only the rows that are between the values you give it.
I used jQuery UI for the `range slider` and I have a normal HTML table.

I cant get it to work and I've tried many different things.
Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
            $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
              range: true,
              min: 0,
              max: 500,
              values: [ 75, 300 ],
              slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
              
            
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
              " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

                $("#ADC_DAC").find("td:nth-child(0)").filter(function () {
                    return parseInt($(this).text()) < $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 );
                }).parent().hide();

                $("#ADC_DAC").find("td:nth-child(0)").filter(function () {
                    return parseInt($(this).text()) > $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 );
                }).parent().hide();
            }
         });
    });
```

The slider has the ID `slider-range` and the table ID `ADC_DAC`.
My table is made up like this:

```
<table id="ADC_DAC">
     <tr>
       <td>h1</td>
       <td>h2</td>
       <td>h3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>23</td>
       <td>test</td>
       <td>test2</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

But then with way more rows and with values between 0 and 500 for the first row (which needs filtering)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were on the right track by trying to change the table properties in the `slide: function() {}`.

However, the code in the function makes use of `find`'s and other unfavourable selectors.

The easiest way would be to simply select the table and go over each row and column like so:

```
var table = document.getElementById("theTable");

for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows (we SKIP the first row: counter starts at 1!)
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
       //iterate through columns: if first column not in range: HIDE, else SHOW
       
       if (j == 0) {             // if first column
           if ($(col).html() >= ui.values[ 0 ] && $(col).html() <= ui.values[ 1 ]) {
               // if in interval
               $(row).show();
           } else {
               $(row).hide();
           }
       }
   }  
}
```

That should do what you want. This solution is much easier than yours because you don't have to deal with the `.parent` and `.children` selectors. Especially for 2D structures like tables, `for loops` are often easier to grasp and maintain a nice level of readability. However, it might not be the shortest code.

Here is the working jsFiddle demo:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qu4ntyl/o1ud4zj7/1/)

[image]

Comment: Nice solution :) How can I do it using [bootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/documentation)? It have not show() and hide()