# Jquery filter table with multiple range sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, filtering

the other day i asked almost the same question

[Jquery slider range: apply range as a filter on table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841464/jquery-slider-range-apply-range-as-a-filter-on-table-rows/27842952#27842952)

i got a fast and good answer on it, and i tought i could change it myself to make it so it accepts multiple range sliders and would filter on them all. I tried writing a function like this:

```
function slide(){
    var table = document.getElementById("ADC_DAC");
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       //iterate through rows (we SKIP the first row: counter starts at 1!)
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
           //iterate through columns: if first column not in range: HIDE, else SHOW

            //if (j == 0) {             // if first column
            if ($(col).html() >= indexmin && $(col).html() <= indexmax && j == 0) {
            // if in interval
                $(row).show();
            } else if ($(col).html() >= minvoltmin && $(col).html() <= minvoltmax && j == 7){
                if (j==7) {
                    $(row).show();
                }
            }else{
                $(row).hide();
            }
        }  
    } 
}
```

`indexmin, indexmax, minvoltmin and the minvoltmax` are the minimal and max from the sliders. 
 the indexmin has to filter in the first column and the minvoltmin is for the 8th column.

the expected output was a table that changes when you move the slider, but it just clears the table and doesnt change anymore after that.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont know if you are supposed to answer your own questions if you found the answer but i found it :D

```
function slide(){
var table = document.getElementById("ADC_DAC");
for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    //iterate through rows (we SKIP the first row: counter starts at 1!)
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        //iterate through columns: if first column not in range: HIDE,else SHOW                                                                    
        // if first column
        if ($(table.rows[i].cells[0]).html() >= indexmin && $(table.rows[i].cells[0]).html() <= indexmax && $(table.rows[i].cells[7]).html() >= minvoltagemin && $(table.rows[i].cells[7]).html() <= minvoltagemax) {
            // if in interval
            $(row).show();
        } else {
            $(row).hide();
        }                                                                     
    }  
} 
}
```

the `slide()` function gets executed everytime one of the sliders move.

hope it helpfull to someone :)